# Can you download Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I've just installed WS2K8 standard from an MSDN DVD with a view to creating a VM running WS2K3 but i can't find Hyper-V anywhere in the 'Server Roles' where it should be.

Is it possible to download extra roles i.e Hyper-V from anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have installed the RTM, then there's a small update you need to install before you can select it as a server role.  See this [MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950050).

Microsoft also offers a [stand-alone hyper-v server](http://www.microsoft.com/hyper-v-server/en/us/how-to-get.aspx) that is free (although you have to license the virtual OS's)  This is a huge ISO & probably *not* what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Thought that might have done the trick but Hyper-V still isn't appearing in the 'Add Roles Wizard' after installing the update you mentioned.

*just realised - i've not d/l'd SP2!  That'll be why
 i'm guessing!

Comment: Installed SP2 and Hyper-V STILL not available.

Comment: Gave up.  Found a WS2K8 R2 x64 Disk so installed that.  Hyper-V was ready & waiting :)

Then told that virtualisation no longer required!

C'est la vie!

Thanks for the suggestions guys (",)

Comment: x64? diod you isntall 32 bit before? That is not ok for prodcution use (i.e. ONLY demonstration) and does not include hyper-v o my knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can download Hyper-V as a seperate package, you will have to aquire the Hyper-V edition of WS2K8. I don't know the license deal MS is using, but I would be suprised if you got Hyper-V for free.

Comment: Actually if you read (cough) the OP he dis install serer 2008 and that (cough) includes Hyper-V ;)